# How can i include version number for API in Response?

Tags: rest, api

I have created API for User and i need to include version number for this API in response. Is it good way or should we just follow version number in request ?

Comment: You can add it as a custom response header

Answer (score 4):

See [REST API Versioning](https://restfulapi.net/versioning/) (restfulapi.net/versioning/) :

> **URI Versioning**
>
> Using the URI is the most straightforward approach (and
>   most commonly used as well) though it does violate the principle that
>   a URI should refer to a unique resource. You are also guaranteed to
>   break client integration when a version is updated.
>
> e.g.
>
> ```
> http://api.example.com/v1
> http://apiv1.example.com
> ```
>
> The version need not be numeric, nor specified using the “v[x]”
>   syntax. Alternatives include dates, project names, seasons or other
>   identifiers that are meaningful enough to the team producing the APIs
>   and flexible enough to change as the versions change.
>
> **Versioning using Custom Request Header A custom header (e.g.**
>
> Accept-version) allows you to preserve your URIs between versions
>   though it is effectively a duplicate of the content negotiation
>   behavior implemented by the existing Accept header.
>
> e.g.
>
> ```
> Accept-version: v1
> Accept-version: v2
> ```
>
> **Versioning using Accept header**
>
> Content negotiation may let you to
>   preserve a clean set of URLs but you still have to deal with the
>   complexity of serving different versions of content somewhere. This
>   burden tends to be moved up the stack to your API controllers which
>   become responsible for figuring out which version of a resource to
>   send. The end result tends to be a more complex API as clients have to
>   know which headers to specify before requesting a resource.
>
> e.g.
>
> ```
> Accept: application/vnd.example.v1+json
> Accept: application/vnd.example+json;version=1.0
> ```

Comment: This answer is great. Just want to add that in a containerized world, I would say it makes sens to have one container per API version. This decouples the versions which can then live in a separate Git branch. That is the URL versioning is the most natural and clean solution.